# expecting IDENT, found ':'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am building a native query for my Spring project. Anyone has any idea what the issue is?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT e.first_name as firstName, e.last_name as lastName, jh.start_date as startDate, jh.end_date as endDate, " +
                "j.job_title as jobName, d.department_name as departmentName FROM JOB_HISTORY jh " +
                "JOIN JOBS j ON jh.JOB_ID = j.JOB_ID " +
                "JOIN DEPARTMENTS d ON JH.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID " +
                "JOIN EMPLOYEES e ON jh.EMPLOYEE_ID = e.EMPLOYEE_ID " +
                "ORDER BY jh.:sortBy :orderBy")
        List<EmployeeJobView> getAllEmployeeJob(String sortBy, String orderBy);
```

> **org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting IDENT,
> found ':' near line 1, column 348** [SELECT e.first_name as firstName,
> e.last_na me as lastName, jh.start_date as startDate, jh.end_date as
> endDate, j.job_title as jobName, d.department_name as departmentName
> FROM JOB_HISTORY jh JOIN JOBS j ON jh.JOB_ID = j.JOB_ID JOIN
> DEPARTMENTS d ON JH.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPAR TMENT_ID JOIN EMPLOYEES e
> ON jh.EMPLOYEE_ID = e.EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY jh.:sortBy :orderBy]

Comment: If you want to build a native query you need to use native sql your database accepts. "jh.:sortBy :orderBy" simply isn't valid sql and looks like you copied it from something that clearly is not a native query, but a prepared statement of some kind where those values later get inserted.

Comment: The problem is jh.:sortBy What should this be?

Comment: And if you want to execute a native query you have to set the attribute nativeQuery=true

Comment: I was trying to reference sortBy and orderBy in the parameter as you can see above:
List<EmployeeJobView> getAllEmployeeJob(String sortBy, String orderBy); 

. It just crashed during the build process, not on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, I'd rewrite last line using SPeL:

```java
"ORDER BY jh.?#{[0]} ?#{[1]}"
```

As [Simon Martinelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045142/simon-martinelli) mentioned, you should use `nativeQuery = true`.

Also see SPeL with JPA guide here https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions.

Comment: Will do. Thank you